# Software-Input-Panel and taskman in WEC7

Tags: shell, windows-ce

I have a WEC7 powered machine and instead of the Explorer shell I have loaded the Taskman shell instead.
But the SIP (Software input panle) is behaving strange. 
When I click a teck box, the SIP is shown for a few seconds and then it is hidden again.
On a WindowsCE 5.0 there are no problems.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the SIP relies on Shell_NotifyIcon being supported and successfully called. This is the API used to include icons in the tray bar. Its implementation relies on a windows with a specific class and title so you may be able to copy the code needed from explorer and include it in your custom version of taskman.
But the best thing to do would be trying to debug the SIP using platform builder. 
As far as I know the code for the virtual keyboards is available. I don't remember about the rest of the implementation but, in any case, trying to run it in debug mode may lead to some hints about the issue.